# Will expo OTA break older version?

Tags: react-native, expo, ota

I know that even after the ejection, I can still OTA the latest js bundles.

However, I’m not sure about this situation:

Version 1.0: Version 1.0 doesn’t involve native Android Mixpush but was already ejected. I published it and released it to the users.

Version 1.1: In this version, I integrated Andoird Mixpush, which involves changes to native modules as well as the JS bundle. Some JS code is depending on the changes in the native modules of V1.1.

My question is: if I do “expo publish” for version 1.1, will this break the users who have downloaded version 1.0? If so, what’s the best practice here to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

What ive previously faced was OTA is a great functionality if you want to update any javascript type functionality that usually doesnt require native dependencies. 
Suppose you want to have a totally new functionality which requires explicit permissions like file storage and something, i prefer publishing new verion to play store / app store for that.

But suppose you want the banner pics to be changed or something like new offers, you can use the OTA functionality. You can always disable the OTA in settings in app.json [expo-ota](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-ota-updates/)

> It is possible to entirely disable OTA JavaScript updates in a standalone app, by setting updates.enabled to false in app.json. This will ignore all code paths that fetch app bundles from Expo's servers. In this case, all updates to your app will need to be routed through the iOS App Store and/or Google Play Store.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts